# Why my async function is not returning the object in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I have an `async` funciton which `fetches` all the `records` from `DB` and return the `object` inside my `controller`

```js
const getMonthlyShipments = async () => {
  try {
    const shipments = await MonthlyShipments.findAll({
      attributes: ["id", ["shipment", "shipment"]],
    });
    console.log("shipments--> : ", shipments.length);
    if (shipments) {
      return {
        status: true,
        message: "Successfully monthly shipments fetched.",
        response: {
          monthlyShipments: shipments,
        },
      };
    } else {
      return {
        status: false,
        message:
          "No monthly shipments data found, please first add monthly shipments",
        response: null,
      };
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    throw CutsomError(error);
  }
};
module.exports = {
  getMonthlyShipments,
};
```

And this is my `api handler` `function` which calls on `api` hit

```
exports.GetMonthlyShipments = async (req, res) => {
try {
    console.log('before execution')
    const result = await getMonthlyShipments()
    console.log('after execution')
    console.log('result : --> ',result)
    res.json(result)
}
catch (error) {
    console.log('Error : ',error)
    res.status(error.code || 500).send({
        code: error.code,
        message: error.message,
        response: null
    })
  }
}
```

My `Sequelize` mode.

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const MonthlyShipments = sequelize.define('monthly_shipments', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    shipment: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    inserted_at: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false
    },
    inserted_by: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true
 });
  return MonthlyShipments;
};
```

Here is my route definition in my `router` file for api `route`

```
router.get('/get-monthly-shipments', catchAsyncErrors(getMonthlyShipments));
```

my `catchAsyncErrors` function is here

```
module.exports = function catchAsyncErrors(fn) {
return (req, res, next) => {
  const routePromise = fn(req, res, next);
  if (routePromise.catch) {
    routePromise.catch((err) => next(err));
   }
 };
};
```

Now the problem is that when i hit the api so it fetches all records from db and logs the `shipments.length` inside of my `controller` and comes to the `return` statement and then it throws following error in `debugger` mode and didn't any thing to postman(api request keeps on pending)

```
Could not load source 'd:\Angular\openport-nodejs\node_modules\sequelize-pool\src\Pool.ts': Unable to retrieve source content.
```

Comment: can you please share code for `catchAsyncErrors` function which wraps your `getMonthlyShipments` function call

Comment: @nishkaush see my updated post. I have included `catchAsyncErrors` function code

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling the issue might be with `catchAsyncErrors` function:

Currently it looks like so:

```js
module.exports = function catchAsyncErrors(fn) {

// the following function should provide next() if no catch involved

return (req, res, next) => {
  const routePromise = fn(req, res, next);
  if (routePromise.catch) {
    routePromise.catch((err) => next(err));
   }
 };
};
```

The logic is saying if routePromise has a `catch` prop on it, check for errors and if there are errors then invoke `next(err)`.

However, what if there isn't any error, the code doesn't know what to do in the case, so its stuck.

Perhaps following adjustment might help by adding a `then` with the `catch`:

```js
module.exports = function catchAsyncErrors(fn) {
return (req, res, next) => {
  const routePromise = fn(req, res, next);
  if (routePromise.catch) {
    routePromise.then(res=>next(res)).catch((err) => next(err));
   }
 };
};
```

Comment: after changing code according to your answer it prints shipments `shipments--> :  4`

`[object Object]`

Comment: and i am receiving `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>[object Object
]</pre>
</body>
</html>` in postman

Comment: i am trying to understand where is `GetMonthlyShipments` getting invoked in your code?? I can't seem to find its invocation point..

Comment: see my own anwer :p exactly i wasn mistaking the thing that you pointed out. basically that was done by auto import feature mistakenly.

Comment: lol so if you now remove the `then` block i asked you to put in, does it still work?

Comment: i removed then block and undo and now it seems like `routePromise.catch((err) => next(err));` again and it's working

Answer (score 0):

So finally i found the problem. I wasn't passing my `api` function in my `route` wihch is `GetMonthlyShipments()`. I was passing my `controller` function directly which is `getMonthlyShipments()`. So i fixed this.